# How to get the default fetch mode in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

How to get the default fetch mode in PDO ?
I thought the method is getAttribute, but there isn't ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE option in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getattribute.php)

And, this is code if you want to know what I want to do

```
    public function query(SQLStatement $sql, $fetch_style = **DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE**) {
        try {
            $s = $this->connection->query((string)$sql, $fetch_style);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            throw new DatabaseException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
        return $s;
    }
```

I want to make the default value for $fetch_style is the default fetch mode attribute (which may have been set before)

Comment: have you trythis $connection = new PDO($connection_string);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: @saty That's to set the default fetch mode. What I want is to get the mode (to know what the default mode is)